# Vue 3 - input type=file does not read QR code. Which are the alternatives?

Tags: vue.js, web, vuejs3, qr-code

I am building a Web App which has 2 instances, one for desktop and one for mobile, they sync through a QR code.
I am trying to get the user to scan the QR code (QR scanner implemented already, it works) after clicking a button which opens the phone camera.

Using input type=file opens my camera, but the QR code is not scanable.
Manually opening the camera from my phone scans the QR and I can navigate to the given link.
I'm guessing since input type=file is waiting for a file upload, the scanning is disabled.

This is what i used:
`<input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" capture="environment">`

Any ideas on how I could implement this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/gruhn/vue-qrcode-reader)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Javascript to access the camera as a Webcam. This would allow you to process the video stream in JS. There are libraries such as [QR Scanner](https://github.com/nimiq/qr-scanner) that provide ways to scan QR codes. They provide some example code in their readme :

```html
<video id="webcam"></video>
<script src="path/to/qr-scanner.umd.min.js"></script>
<script>
    const videoElem = document.getElementById("webcam");
    const qrScanner = new QrScanner(
        videoElem,
        result => console.log('decoded qr code:', result),
        { /* your options or returnDetailedScanResult: true if you're not specifying any other options */ },
    );
</script>
```